# Out of stack space error when releasing memory for a linked list when it contains more than around 6000 elements

Tags: excel, stack-overflow, vba

I've got a doubly linked list in VBA with a Class_Terminate subroutine that loops through the elements disconnecting them so that memory can be released. All works well until the list contains more than about 6500 elements, when I get error 28: Out of stack space.

I don't see any obvious recursion and the stack space for the Class_Terminate subroutine shouldn't be growing with the number of elements (but who knows what the VBA interpreter is doing?....)

Any ideas? All code to replicate below

## CQueue class module

```
Option Explicit

Private m_start As CQElement
Private m_end As CQElement

Private m_maxLength As Long
Private m_length As Long


Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    'Debug.Print "Terminating CFerQueue with " & m_length & " elements"

    'When the queue is large (6,500 elements or so)
    'this runs out of stack space.

    If Not m_start Is Nothing Then
        Dim element As CQElement
        Set element = m_start.m_next
        While Not element Is Nothing
            Set element.m_prev = Nothing
            Set element = element.m_next
        Wend
    End If
End Sub

Public Property Get maxLength() As Long
    maxLength = m_maxLength
End Property
Public Property Let maxLength(theMaxLength As Long)
    m_maxLength = theMaxLength
    If m_length > m_maxLength Then
        Dim removeCount As Long
        removeCount = m_length - m_maxLength
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To removeCount
            remove
        Next i
    End If
End Property

Public Sub enq(item As Variant)
    Dim newItem As CQElement
    Set newItem = New CQElement
    Set newItem.item = item


    If m_length > 0 Then
        Set m_end.m_next = newItem
        Set newItem.m_prev = m_end
    End If
    Set m_end = newItem

    If m_length = m_maxLength And m_maxLength > 0 Then  
        Set m_start = m_start.m_next
        Set m_start.m_prev.m_next = Nothing
        Set m_start.m_prev = Nothing
    Else
        m_length = m_length + 1
        If m_length = 1 Then
            Set m_start = newItem
        End If
    End If
End Sub


'Removes from the start
Public Function remove() As Boolean
    If Not m_start Is Nothing Then
        Set m_start = m_start.m_next
        Set m_start.m_prev.m_next = Nothing
        Set m_start.m_prev = Nothing
        m_length = m_length - 1
        remove = True
    End If
End Function
```

## CQElement class module

```
Option Explicit

Public item As Variant
Public m_next As CQElement
Public m_prev As CQElement
```

## Test subroutine

```
Public Sub testQueueBounds()
    Dim elementCount As Long: elementCount = 7000

    Dim q As CQueue: Set q = New CQueue
    q.maxLength = elementCount

    Dim element As CSomeClass

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To elementCount
        Set element = New CSomeClass
        Call q.enq(element)
    Next i

    Set q = Nothing

End Sub
```

## CSomeClass class module

```
Option Explicit

'This is entirely empty
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Terminate` method is not fully releasing all references to your linked list, therefore the list objects are not distroyed.

Change it to this

```
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    If Not m_start Is Nothing Then
        If m_length > 1 Then
            Set m_start = m_start.m_next

            Do While Not m_start Is m_end
                Set m_start.m_prev.m_prev = Nothing
                Set m_start.m_prev.m_next = Nothing

                Set m_start.m_prev = Nothing
                Set m_start = m_start.m_next
            Loop
        End If

        Set m_start.m_prev = Nothing
        Set m_start.m_next = Nothing
        Set m_start = Nothing
        Set m_end = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Very interesting Chris. Your destructor gets rid of the stack overflow problem thank you. However it is not because it fully releases all references (the original destructor also fully releases all references). The difference between the destructor you've kindly offered and the original is in the ORDER of release. The original releases the linked list first and then the elements follow, your proposal releases the elements first and then the linked list itself. 
Any ideas as to why the order makes a difference to stack space?

Comment: BTW Adding the statement
    "Set element.m_prev.m_next = Nothing"
to the original destructor achieves the same thing

Comment: @OldSchool Your original `Terminate` routine does not release `m_start` or `m_end`.  It also only sets the `m_prev` elements to Nothing, leaving the `m_next` element intact.  As a result none of the linked list is released.

Comment: Sorry but that is incorrect. `m_start` and `m_end` are released when the list is released because the list is the only thing pointing to them. The same goes for all the nodes. Once you sever the reverse link, the only thing pointing to them is the list, so when it goes they all go. Just run a test with some `Debug.Print` statements in the `Class_Terminate` routines to see for yourself.

Comment: So the crux of the question remains unanswered. i.e. Why is stack space being consumed by an iteration where the stack frame should be fixed size? And why does the order of object release seem to matter?

Comment: No further insights? Anybody?